# Modify the contents of a file in powershell

Tags: file, powershell

I have a situation where I need to modify the contents of a file using PowerShell.  The string already there will be similar to `ToolsVersion="3.5"`.  However I can not be positive that `"3.5"` will always be what is inside the quotes.  I need to change the value inside the quotes to `"12.0"`.  Is there a way to find the `"ToolsVersion="` in the file, then modify the value inside the quotes that follows it?

Comment: Check out regex and `-replace` (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings.aspx)

Comment: Is this for an C# or VB project file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Get-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx), [`-replace`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings.aspx), and [`Out-File`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx):

```powershell
(Get-Content C:\path\to\file.txt) -replace 'ToolsVersion=".*?"', 'ToolsVersion="12.0"' | Out-File C:\path\to\file.txt
```

Comment: I think it's generally best to avoid using zero-length assertions for static strings, because they make the regex engine work a lot harder. It would be more efficient to use `-replace 'ToolsVersion=".*?"', 'ToolsVersion="12.0"'`. The difference can be significant if a large amount of data is processed. (`-replace 'ToolsVersion=".*?(?=")', 'ToolsVersion="12.0'` would be just as efficient, but more fancy with no advantage.)

Comment: Even better, use `"[^"]+"` since you know that the version will never contain another doublequote (wouldn't be valid XML otherwise)